# How do I get the output of a single field?

Tags: nodes

How do I get the output of a field of a node?
I have some weird subpage construct using entity references (one 'main' node and a few 'sub'-nodes).

Each of these nodes have a header image to be displayed above the content. What I am trying to do is for the sub-nodes to 'inherit' the header image of the main node.

I implemented `hook_node_view` and I have got the node, I just don't know how to build the renderable array for it.

```
function hook_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if($view_mode == 'full'){
    if((!isset($build['field_headerimage']) || !isset($build['field_headerimage'][0])) && $entity->hasField('field_location')){
      $location = $entity->get('field_location')->referencedEntities();
      if(is_array($location) && isset($location[0])) {
        $node = $location[0];
        dsm('yay, now what?');
        dsm($node->label());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question seems to be like so:

```
$build['field_headerimage'] = $node->get('field_headerimage')->view();
```